# Get Email id from twitter after enabled requesting email permissions for my app

Tags: php, api

How to get Email id from twitter after twitter enabled requesting email permissions for my app?

I'm not getting the email id from my API. After read doc, I got that there is another URL for Email id: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json

And I am using the below code

```
$status = $connection->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json', array('include_email'=>'true'))
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Is there any one.... plzz help me